# Non greedy python regex

Tags: python, regex, non-greedy

I'm trying to work my way through some regular expressions; I'm using python.

My task right now is to scrape newspaper articles and look for instances where people have died. Once I have a relevant article, I'm trying to snag the death count for some other things. I'm trying to come up with a few patterns, but I'm having difficulty with one in particular. Take this sample article section:

> SANAA, Oct 21 (Reuters) - Three men thought to be al Qaeda militants
>   were killed in an apparent U.S. drone attack on a car in Yemen on
>   Sunday, tribal sources and local officials said.

The code that I'm using to snag the 'three' first does a replace on the entire document, so that the 'three' becomes a '3' before any patterns at all are applied. The pattern relevant to this example is this:

```
re.compile(r"(\d+)\s(:?men|women|children|people)?.*?(:?were|have been)? killed")
```

The idea is that this pattern will start with a number, be followed by an optional noun such as one of the ones listed, then have a minimum amount of clutter before finding 'dead' or 'died'. I want to leave room so that this pattern would catch:

```
3 people have been killed since Sunday
```

and still catch the instance in the example:

```
3 men thought to be al qaeda militants were killed
```

The problem is that the pattern I'm using is collecting the date from the first part of the article, and returning a count of 21. No amount of fiddling so far has enabled me to limit the scope to the digit right beside the word men, followed by the participial phrase, then the relevant 'were killed'.

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm definitely no guru when it comes to RE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make the `men|women|children` optional, i.e. take out the question mark after the closing parenthesis. The regex engine will match at the first possible place, regardless of whether repetition operators are greedy or stingy.

Alternatively, or additionally, make the "anything here" pattern only match non-numbers, i.e. replace `.*?` with `\D*?`

Comment: The \D worked and seems to make the most sense syntax-wise, and be most scalable.

Answer (score 2):

This is because, you have used the quantifier `?`, which matches `0` or `1` of your `(:?men|women|children|people)` after your digit. So, `21` will match. since it has `0` of them.

Try removing your quantifier after it, to match exactly one of them: -

```
re.compile(r"(\d+)\s(?:men|women|children|people).*?(?:were|have been)? killed")
```

**UPDATE**: - To use `? quantifier` and still get the required result, you need to use `Look-Ahead` Regex, to make sure that your `digit` is not followed by a string containing a `hiephen(-)` as is in your example.

```
re.compile(r"(\d+)(?!.*?-.*?)\s(?:men|women|children|people)?.*?(?:were|have been)? killed")
```

Comment: Specifying an explicit repeat count of one is completely redundant.

Comment: I don't want the {1} because there may be an instance where the article says '3 were killed on sunday in a blast...'

Comment: @tripleee. Yeah that's true. I have quoted that thing. But `{1}` gives him a way to use another `quantifier`.

Comment: @hyleaus. Then you need to use `Look-Behind`. To check whether it's preceded by a `hiephen(-)`, as is in your example.

Comment: I tried your rendition, but the interpreter told me a look behind requires a fixed-width pattern

Comment: @hyleaus. Sorry, there was a problem. Edited the regex. Try the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

You use **wrong syntax** `(:?...)`. You probably wanted to use `(?:...)`.

---

Use regex pattern

```
(\d+).*?\b(?:men|women|children|people|)\b.*?\b(?:were|have been|)\b.*?\bkilled\b
```

or if just spaces are allowed between those words, then

```
(\d+)\s+(?:men|women|children|people|)\s+(?:were|have been|)\s+killed\b
```

Comment: You're correct. It was the wrong syntax, but because I was only interested in the .group(1), it didn't affect the results. Thanks for the attention though.